# Fundamental theorem of algebra and quaternions

Tags: functions, roots, quaternions

I'm not sure if the fundamental theorem of algebra extends to every possible and imaginable numbers (real, complex, quaternions, etc.) but here's my question anyway.

Let $f(x) = x^2-2ax+(a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2)$ and let the quaternion $q=a+bi+cj+dk$, where the coefficients of $q$ are real. We can easily verify that $q$ and $\bar{q}$ are roots of $f(x)$.

But there are 2 other real roots $x_1$ and $x_2$ to $f(x)$:

$$x_1 = a - \sqrt{-b^2-c^2-d^2}$$
$$x_2 = a + \sqrt{-b^2-c^2-d^2} $$

Shouldn't the fundamental theorem of Algebra forbid that? Because I thought that a polynomial of degree $n$ can only have $n$ distinct roots maximum, which is not the case here since $f(x)$ is a 2nd degree polynomial but has 4 root distinct roots.

Can anyone enlighten me, please?

Thank you

Comment: Taking a rotation of $\pm\pi/2$ around any unit vector in $\Bbb{R}^3$) shows $f(x)=x^2+1$ has infinitely roots in $\Bbb{H}$. It holds because $R=\Bbb{H}$ is a non-commutative ring so $R[x]$ is a ring of functions $\Bbb{R \to H}$ (with the pointwise multiplication of functions) where $\Bbb{R} $ is the center of $\Bbb{H}$, it isn't a ring of functions $\Bbb{H \to H}$ and as such $f(\alpha) = 0$ doesn't mean $f(x) =  (x-\alpha) g(x)$ for some polynomial $g$.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the concepts you brought up. I do not know what H represents and what it can do

Comment: ?? $\Bbb{H}$ is the set of quaternions, a ring. $R[x]$ is the ring of polynomials with coefficients in a ring $R$ with obvious addition and multiplication given by $ax^n = x^n a$, ie. assuming $x$ commutes with every element in $R$, ie. when evaluating polynomials (to check if $f(c) = 0$) taking $x=c$ in the center of $R$. With $R = \Bbb{H}$ the center is $\Bbb{R}$.

Comment: And I meant $x^4-1$ has infinitely many roots instead of $x^2+1$ (for a quaternion $q$ representing a $\pm \pi /2$ rotation then $q^4 = 1$)

Comment: the proof of the FTA demands commutativity.   The quaternions lack this.

Comment: Thank you Randall :)

Comment: @Michael: If your question has been answered by the comments, you could write up a short summary of the answer, post it as an answer and accept it so that the question doesn't remain unanswered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Port of @Randall's comment into an answer)

This is because the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra requires commutativity, and quaternions lack this property.